# Manage Subscriptions url on iOS is broken

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10

I'm trying to direct the user to iOS subscription management screen in Settings.

Apple documentation here:
[Letting Users Manage Subscriptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html)

Suggests opening this URL:
https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions

This was working but seems to be broken now on iOS 10 & iOS 9.3.4. I just get a white screen with the Carrier/Battery bar. This is true even if I just Paste that URL into Safari.

Comment: It looks like Apple have a problem at the moment

Answer (score 0):

UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions")!)